# Very Slow Spark-Phoenix Integration

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-phoenix

I am using spark-phoenix integration to load data from a dataframe into a Phoenix table. Unfortunately this is ridiculously slow - pushing 23 rows of 25 columns each takes 7-8 seconds. This is with two executors with two cores each, meaning it's actually twice as slow. This makes it unusable in my case, since it is planned to use in a streaming application - the number of records dropped in a 15 second window take up to a minute to load.

When I look at the Spark History Server, I see two really strange things:

- The slowest part, by far, is 'saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile at DataFrameFunctions.scala:55', so the problem is not in my code.
- For 23 rows, 200 tasks are launched. This seems excessive.

Does anybody have experience with how I could improve these loading speeds? Ideally I want to keep using Phoenix in some way, since we have secondary indexes on the table.